# InvalidOperationException while using NamedPipes on Windows XP and .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, named-pipes

I am using a named pipe to communicate between two processes using .Net 3.5. This works fine on Windows 7, but somehow does not under Windows XP.

I am getting an InvalidOperationException there. Here is my attempt of translation of the german message: "Pipe handle has not been set. Did your PipeStream implementation call InitializeHandle?"

I have created a test project for this:
http://www.chinery.de/dateien/NamedPipeTest.zip

In the application, you can hit "Connect" and will see the name of the Pipe. On the right hand side, you can enter a message that will be sent through the pipe, if all goes well.

As I have said, the problem only appears on Windows XP for me.

Does anyone have a clue on this?

Comment: I managed to get this exception by doing something stupid: I tried to specify NamedPipeClientStream.ReadMode before calling NamedPipeClientStream.Connect().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution myself. It was the pipe client creation:

```
NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream("localhost", PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut)
```

I had to change this to:
    NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut)

(change server name from "localhost" to ".")

This somehow worked on Windows 7, but not on XP. Now it finally works on both systems.

Comment: So I'm trying to solve a similar issue, with a c# client and C++ server on Win 7, and I have to use `"localhost"`.  If I use `"."` then creation of the `NamedPipeClientStream` throws.  So bizarre!

Answer (score 5):

I recently ran into this issue myself. My solution was to set the `NamedPipeClientStream.ReadMode` *after* calling `NamedPipeClientStream.Connect()`. Otherwise I would get the `Pipe handle has not been set. Did your PipeStream implementation call InitializeHandle?` exception mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

It might have permission issue: So, need to provide required access rights.

```
PipeSecurity _pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();
PipeAccessRule psEveryone = new PipeAccessRule("Everyone", PipeAccessRights.FullControl,
    System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);

_pipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(psEveryone);

NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(PipeName, PipeDirection.In,
    1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 4, 4, _pipeSecurity);
```

And to overcome the problem of listening only once follow this step:
Right click on respective service > Properties > Log On > Log on as: Local System Account and tick Allow service to interact with desktop.
Or Go to ServiceProcessInstaller property and Set account as LocalSystem.